# Need a secure password generator recommendation

Tags: java, password-generator

Can anybody recommend a secure password generator available under a Apache or LGPL licence for Java?

Comment: What stops you from writing a 1~3 line utility method using `java.util.Random` or `java.util.UUID` for this?

Comment: @BalusC at the VERY least you'd want to use java.security.SecureRandom

Comment: The security is the most important aspect. Its for a one time password that will be used by an unverified user. I need to know that the passwords will be very strong.

Comment: Yes, `SecureRandom` is indeed cryptographically stronger, but that doesn't change the question.

Comment: http://www.texamples.com/how-to-generate-random-passwords-in-java/ this may help.

Comment: Try this Password Generator https://www.tutorialkart.com/password-generator/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would not worry that much about generating incredible strong one time passwords. Make the password long and it should not be a problem with brute force granted you limit how long the password is valid. If the password is only valid for say 1 hour then it will not be a problem if the password remains unused. And in that time span it is not likely that someone will get to crack it using brute force.

It is also important that you only let the one time password work just one time. This way, if the password is intercepted the user will notice when the one time password has expired and can take appropriate actions.

I'd go for Apache Commons [RandomStringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html) and let the password be 10-15 characters of letters and numbers.

...though it always is a question of how paranoid you want to be. This solution would be fine for a regular web application, but not good enough for a bank...

Comment: [RandomStringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html) is not well suited for password generation as it is based on standard [Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html), but not on [SecureRandom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html)

Comment: Unless you manually specify secure random generator, see [RandomStringUtils.random](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html#random(int,%20int,%20int,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20char[],%20java.util.Random))

Comment: Why is this the top answer? "Don't worry about password security, it's not important."  Password security is one of the most abused, misunderstood problems with security today.  Please stop spreading stuff like this.  Make your passwords secure.

Answer (score 5):

It's in .net but should be trivial to convert. Maybe a little too much for most, but this is the go to implementation that I always use in my apps.  It is an implementation that I found some time ago, and did some modifications to, I can't recall the original author, but I will do a quick search to see if I can give him appropriate credit.

```
public static string GenerateRandomString(int minLength, int maxLength, int minLCaseCount, int minUCaseCount, int minNumCount, int minSpecialCount)
        {
            char[] randomString;

            const string LCaseChars = "abcdefgijkmnopqrstwxyz";
            const string UCaseChars = "ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTWXYZ";
            const string NumericChars = "23456789";
            const string SpecialChars = "*$-+?_&=!%{}/";

            Hashtable charGroupsUsed = new Hashtable();
            charGroupsUsed.Add("lcase", minLCaseCount);
            charGroupsUsed.Add("ucase", minUCaseCount);
            charGroupsUsed.Add("num", minNumCount);
            charGroupsUsed.Add("special", minSpecialCount);

            // Because we cannot use the default randomizer, which is based on the
            // current time (it will produce the same "random" number within a
            // second), we will use a random number generator to seed the
            // randomizer.

            // Use a 4-byte array to fill it with random bytes and convert it then
            // to an integer value.
            byte[] randomBytes = new byte[4];

            // Generate 4 random bytes.
            RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
            rng.GetBytes(randomBytes);

            // Convert 4 bytes into a 32-bit integer value.
            int seed = (randomBytes[0] & 0x7f) << 24 |
                        randomBytes[1] << 16 |
                        randomBytes[2] << 8 |
                        randomBytes[3];

            // Create a randomizer from the seed.
            Random random = new Random(seed);

            // Allocate appropriate memory for the password.
            if (minLength < maxLength)
            {
                randomString = new char[random.Next(minLength, maxLength + 1)];
            }
            else
            {
                randomString = new char[minLength];
            }

            int requiredCharactersLeft = minLCaseCount + minUCaseCount + minNumCount + minSpecialCount;

            // Build the password.
            for (int i = 0; i < randomString.Length; i++)
            {
                string selectableChars = "";

                // if we still have plenty of characters left to acheive our minimum requirements.
                if (requiredCharactersLeft < randomString.Length - i)
                {
                    // choose from any group at random
                    selectableChars = LCaseChars + UCaseChars + NumericChars + SpecialChars;
                }
                else // we are out of wiggle room, choose from a random group that still needs to have a minimum required.
                {
                    // choose only from a group that we need to satisfy a minimum for.
                    foreach (DictionaryEntry charGroup in charGroupsUsed)
                    {
                        if ((int)charGroup.Value > 0)
                        {
                            switch (charGroup.Key.ToString())
                            {
                                case "lcase":
                                    selectableChars += LCaseChars;
                                    break;
                                case "ucase":
                                    selectableChars += UCaseChars;
                                    break;
                                case "num":
                                    selectableChars += NumericChars;
                                    break;
                                case "special":
                                    selectableChars += SpecialChars;
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Now that the string is built, get the next random character.
                char nextChar = selectableChars[random.Next(0, selectableChars.Length - 1)];

                // Tac it onto our password.
                randomString[i] = nextChar;

                // Now figure out where it came from, and decrement the appropriate minimum value.
                if (LCaseChars.Contains(nextChar))
                {
                    charGroupsUsed["lcase"] = (int)charGroupsUsed["lcase"] - 1;
                    if ((int)charGroupsUsed["lcase"] >= 0)
                    {
                        requiredCharactersLeft--;
                    }
                }
                else if (UCaseChars.Contains(nextChar))
                {
                    charGroupsUsed["ucase"] = (int)charGroupsUsed["ucase"] - 1;
                    if ((int)charGroupsUsed["ucase"] >= 0)
                    {
                        requiredCharactersLeft--;
                    }
                }
                else if (NumericChars.Contains(nextChar))
                {
                    charGroupsUsed["num"] = (int)charGroupsUsed["num"] - 1;
                    if ((int)charGroupsUsed["num"] >= 0)
                    {
                        requiredCharactersLeft--;
                    }
                }
                else if (SpecialChars.Contains(nextChar))
                {
                    charGroupsUsed["special"] = (int)charGroupsUsed["special"] - 1;
                    if ((int)charGroupsUsed["special"] >= 0)
                    {
                        requiredCharactersLeft--;
                    }
                }
            }
            return new string(randomString);
        }
```

### Edit

I believe I started with the code posted at
http://www.obviex.com/Samples/Password.aspx.
Though the code now has a few more features.

Comment: Great job Matthew. This worked perfectly (when converted to Java) - I'm attaching the Java version to a new response.

Comment: @eugene is there a java version already?

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example using Commons. It creates an Alphanumeric password between 8 and 20 characters long.

```
public String getRandomPassword() {
    StringBuffer password = new StringBuffer(20);
    int next = RandomUtils.nextInt(13) + 8;
    password.append(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(next));
    return password.toString();
}
```

**UPDATE**
RandomUtils.nextInt returns a number between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive) so to get a value between 8 and 20 characters inclusive, the argument value should be 13. I've corrected the code above.

**UPDATE**
As noted in a comment below, this could be written without using StringBuffer. Here is a modified one line version:

```
return RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(RandomUtils.nextInt(13) + 8);
```

Comment: You don't need the StringBuffer here, unless you want to add more to the generated password. (And you would probably be using StringBuilder if you do)

Comment: Why randomize the length of the password?

Comment: Why not randomize the length of the password?

Comment: @Dave: Because it adds no value to do so.  This also means sometimes you're creating a password with 33 bits of security, and sometimes with 82 (assuming this is base-62).  Here's a better plan: decide what the maximum password length you're willing to have is, and choose a password with that length, or at least long enough that you get 128-bits of security.

Answer (score 4):

For those interested, here's Matthew's code, converted to Java

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;

public class PasswordGenerator {

public static String GenerateRandomString(int minLength, int maxLength, int minLCaseCount,     int minUCaseCount, int minNumCount, int minSpecialCount)
{
    char[] randomString;

    String LCaseChars = "abcdefgijkmnopqrstwxyz";
    String UCaseChars = "ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTWXYZ";
    String NumericChars = "23456789";
    String SpecialChars = "*$-+?_&=!%{}/";

    Map<String,Integer> charGroupsUsed = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    charGroupsUsed.put("lcase", minLCaseCount);
    charGroupsUsed.put("ucase", minUCaseCount);
    charGroupsUsed.put("num", minNumCount);
    charGroupsUsed.put("special", minSpecialCount);

    // Because we cannot use the default randomizer, which is based on the
    // current time (it will produce the same "random" number within a
    // second), we will use a random number generator to seed the
    // randomizer.

    // Use a 4-byte array to fill it with random bytes and convert it then
    // to an integer value.
    byte[] randomBytes = new byte[4];

    // Generate 4 random bytes.
    new Random().nextBytes(randomBytes);

    // Convert 4 bytes into a 32-bit integer value.
    int seed = (randomBytes[0] & 0x7f) << 24 |
                randomBytes[1] << 16 |
                randomBytes[2] << 8 |
                randomBytes[3];

    // Create a randomizer from the seed.
    Random random = new Random(seed);

    // Allocate appropriate memory for the password.
    int randomIndex = -1;
    if (minLength < maxLength)
    {
        randomIndex = random.nextInt((maxLength-minLength)+1)+minLength;
        randomString = new char[randomIndex];
    }
    else
    {
        randomString = new char[minLength];
    }

    int requiredCharactersLeft = minLCaseCount + minUCaseCount + minNumCount + minSpecialCount;

    // Build the password.
    for (int i = 0; i < randomString.length; i++)
    {
        String selectableChars = "";

        // if we still have plenty of characters left to acheive our minimum requirements.
        if (requiredCharactersLeft < randomString.length - i)
        {
            // choose from any group at random
            selectableChars = LCaseChars + UCaseChars + NumericChars + SpecialChars;
        }
        else // we are out of wiggle room, choose from a random group that still needs to have a minimum required.
        {
            // choose only from a group that we need to satisfy a minimum for.
            for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> charGroup : charGroupsUsed.entrySet())
            {
                if ((int)charGroup.getValue() > 0)
                {
                    if("lcase".equals(charGroup.getKey()) ){
                        selectableChars += LCaseChars;
                    }
                    else if("ucase".equals(charGroup.getKey())){
                        selectableChars += UCaseChars;
                    }
                    else if("num".equals(charGroup.getKey())){
                        selectableChars += NumericChars;
                    }
                    else if("special".equals(charGroup.getKey())){
                        selectableChars += SpecialChars;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Now that the string is built, get the next random character.
        randomIndex = random.nextInt((selectableChars.length())-1);
        char nextChar = selectableChars.charAt(randomIndex);

        // Tac it onto our password.
        randomString[i] = nextChar;

        // Now figure out where it came from, and decrement the appropriate minimum value.
        if (LCaseChars.indexOf(nextChar) > -1)
        {
            charGroupsUsed.put("lcase",charGroupsUsed.get("lcase") - 1);
            if (charGroupsUsed.get("lcase") >= 0)
            {
                requiredCharactersLeft--;
            }
        }
        else if (UCaseChars.indexOf(nextChar) > -1)
        {
            charGroupsUsed.put("ucase",charGroupsUsed.get("ucase") - 1);
            if (charGroupsUsed.get("ucase") >= 0)
            {
                requiredCharactersLeft--;
            }
        }
        else if (NumericChars.indexOf(nextChar) > -1)
        {
            charGroupsUsed.put("num", charGroupsUsed.get("num") - 1);
            if (charGroupsUsed.get("num") >= 0)
            {
                requiredCharactersLeft--;
            }
        }
        else if (SpecialChars.indexOf(nextChar) > -1)
        {
            charGroupsUsed.put("special",charGroupsUsed.get("special") - 1);
            if (charGroupsUsed.get("special") >= 0)
            {
                requiredCharactersLeft--;
            }
        }
    }
    return new String(randomString);
}

}
```

And a unit test

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class PasswordGeneratorTest {

@Test
public void testPasswordCreation(){

    System.out.println(PasswordGenerator.GenerateRandomString(8,25,3,1,1,1));

}

}
```

Comment: Nice! Two remarks: Where are the `0` and `1` in `NumericChars` property. And second: I would user [SecureRandom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) for this.

Comment: @MartijnBurger way late, but in case anyone else wonders.  It's common to avoid look alike characters in these generators 0O, 1Il, just to reduce the possible frustration of the user who has to enter it somewhere later.

Comment: Hey Matthew, thanks for the reply. Which character set is that? Base-58, which is specifically designed for that purpose ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base58)) has a `1` and an `o`.

Answer (score 0):

[Password Safe](http://passwordsafe.sourceforge.net/) is open source (under the Artistic License) and includes password generation code.

Answer (score 0):

I added a Golang implementation that is similar to the C#/Java versions. It is available under Apache 2.0. The source is located here:

https://github.com/deftlabs/dlshared/blob/master/password_utils.go

Answer (score -1):

You can easily implement it using Random and the built in MessageDigest implementations.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.security.*;
import java.math.*;

public class RandPassGen {
    public static String genPass( int chars ) {
        Random r = new Random();
        MessageDigest md = null;

        try {
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        } catch ( NoSuchAlgorithmException e ) {
            System.out.println( "Unsupported Algorithm!" );
            return null;
        }

        byte[] entropy = new byte[1024];
        r.nextBytes(entropy);
        md.update( entropy , 0, 1024 );

        return new BigInteger(1, md.digest()).toString(16).substring(0, chars);
    }

    public static void main( String[] av ) {
        Integer chars = Integer.valueOf(av[0]);
        if ((chars < 0) || (chars > 32)) {
            System.out.println( "Generate between 0 and 32 characters." );
            return;
        }

        System.out.println( genPass( chars ) ); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hashing the output of a badly seeded PRNG doesn't turn it into a good PRNG.