# Open Source Password Generator for android

Tags: android, encryption, open-source, passwords

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need a secure password generator recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090021/need-a-secure-password-generator-recommendation)

I am Looking for an Open Source Password generator lib for android. Can you point where can i found such a lib ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Random Class in java instead of using a Library for it. You can Reduce your MemorySize too by doing this .

**or**

Refer this link : 
http://www.texamples.com/how-to-generate-random-passwords-in-java/

Comment: I think you need `SecureRandom` not `Random`.